# Backlight control for official Raspberry Pi 7 inch touchscreen

Tags: raspbian, display, touchscreen

I recently received the official Raspberry Pi 7 inch Touchscreen. It works fine so far, but I would like to control the brightness and switch off/on the backlight.
I tried `xbacklight`, it is not working. `/sys/class/backlight` is empty. I didn't find a clue in `/sys/devices/`.

Comment: Raspbian Wheezy is installed. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` was executed.

Answer (score 2):

There apparently have been 2 versions of the 7" touchcreen. The 1.0 versions did not support adjusting the backlight brightness, but the 1.1 versions do, and you can do it by setting a value from 0 to 255 like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 80 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness"
```

There's a lengthy thread here that discusses this feature:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=120968

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The user said, "`/sys/class/backlight` is empty".

Comment: If you read the linked thread, I think the reason for /sys/class/backlight being empty is either you have the older 1.0 touchscreen, or you need to update the Pi's firmware to get the touchscreen support

Answer (score 0):

I have found that as of 01/12/17 the method Kevin mentioned in his answer to `echo` to `bl_power` to turn the backlight on/off does not always work [consistently](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59574/official-touchscreen-backlight-inconsistent-control?noredirect=1#comment93693_59574).

As the question linked describes, an alternative to turning the backlight off via `bl_power` is setting the brightness to 0 in the brightness file which does the same thing in my experience.

Also, in order to not have to use `sudo sh -c` create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/backlight-permissions.rules` and add this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight",RUN+="/bin/chmod 666 /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness /sys/class/backlight/%k/bl_power"
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem in the end i sent it back as it broke within a 2 weeks the problem is due to the on board graphics driver raspberry say there are going to release it i class the screen as a unfinished prototype they should not have released it without backlight support or even a dim switch would do it does start to hurt eyes u could vnc to an android tablet as a altenitive

Comment: Please make an effort to use reasonable grammar.